# Graph Algorithms post and pre counting

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I'm programming depth first algorithm.

input is a vertex and a adjacency list
here is my data:

```
{'N': ['X'],
 'X': ['N', 'A'],
 'A': ['X', 'B', 'D', 'C'],
 'B': ['A', 'H', 'G'],
 'C': ['D', 'A'],
 'D': ['C', 'A', 'F', 'L'],
 'F': ['D', 'L'],
 'L': ['D', 'F'],
 'H': ['B', 'G'],
 'G': ['H', 'B'],
 'Q': ['W'],
 'W': ['Q']}
```

here is my code:

```
def explore (node):

    node[visited] = True
    clock +=1
    node[pre_time] = clock
    
    for neighbor of node:
        if not neighbor[visited]:
            explore(neighbor)
    clock+=1
    node[post_time] = clock
```

now this works fine... except that my pre_time and post_time is messed up
I want my post time calculated *after* I'm done exploring all the neighbours

but my outcome is like this

```
{'N': {'post': 2, 'pre': 1, 'visited': True}, 'X': {'post': 3, 'pre': 2, 'visited': True}, 'A': {'post': 4, 'pre': 3, 'visited': True}, 'B': {'post': 5, 'pre': 4, 'visited': True}, 'C': {'post': 6, 'pre': 5, 'visited': True}, 'D': {'post': 5, 'pre': 4, 'visited': True}, 'F': {'post': 6, 'pre': 5, 'visited': True}, 'L': {'post': 7, 'pre': 6, 'visited': True}, 'H': {'post': 6, 'pre': 5, 'visited': True}, 'G': {'post': 7, 'pre': 6, 'visited': True}, 'Q': {'post': None, 'pre': None, 'visited': False}, 'W': {'post': None, 'pre': None, 'visited': False}})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is a reproducible code in Colab

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CTxyDRcCeNuh8b68Jpb8IW-8oy56JSQg?usp=sharing

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Share more code (where you're calling the explore())

Comment: I shared a link

Comment: It looks like you expect `clock` to be a global variable, but it is scoped to the function call.  Initialize it outside of the function, and then put the line `global clock` inside of the function and your problem should go away.

Comment: You are a genius @btilly, it worked like magic. Thank you